# Can anyone help to get out of this error unverified error and DCO Eroor while i commit

Tags: github, github-for-windows

`[hello ,(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdHKH.png)ll i am making  committo github account] 1.when i got to gihub to check about commit  this error shows (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOEvc.png)`

2.It is showing unverified with this error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HccHF.png)
plese help me to resolve me this error

1.when i got to gihub to check about commit  this error shows can anyne help me to get out of this error

Answer (score 0):

signed commits help to verify your the autor of the commit. Some repositorys require it for safety reasons. GitHub has [documentation](https://docs.github.com/de/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits) for this. You may create a key and add it to your account to contribute.

Comment: Yes i added but it will not worked

Comment: @Jatin did you add your public key to your github account?